# runover an array in smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

I have a multidimensional array that i send to a template where i use smarty.

The array looks like:

```
array (size=2)
 'gender' => 
   array (size=2)
    0 => string 'male' (length=4)
    1 => string 'female' (length=6)
 'states' => 
   array (size=11)
    0 => string 'Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires' (length=31)
    1 => string 'Buenos Aires' (length=12)
    2 => string 'Catamarca' (length=9)
    3 => string 'Chaco' (length=5)
    4 => string 'Chubut' (length=6)
    5 => string 'Cordoba' (length=7)
    6 => string 'Corrientes' (length=10)
    7 => string 'Entre Rios' (length=10)
    8 => string 'Formosa' (length=7)
    9 => string 'Jujuy' (length=5)
    10 => string 'La Pampa' (length=8)
```

what i want to achieve is this: i can only show 4 or less elements from each array depending on how many elements it has. For example, for the subarray "gender" i show both male and female. But, for the subarray "states" i only have to show the first 4 elements, and  then to add a legend with a link "show more".

This is so far what i coded:

```
{if $ns eq 'states'}
<dt>Provincia</dt>
{assign var="n" value="0"}
{counter start=0 print=false assign=n}
{foreach from=$r key=k item=v}
   {counter print=false}                            
   {if counter lt 3}
    <dd>{$v}</dd>
   {elseif counter eq 3}
    <dd>Ver más<dd>
   {/if}

{/foreach}
n = {$n}
{/if}
```

It's not giving me the results i want. I don't know how to "hide" the elements when they are more than 4. I could only iterate 4 times, but in that case, how would i manipulate the subarray if i don't have a foreach?

The Output should look like this:

```
Gender
  Male
  Female

States
  Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires
  Buenos Aires
  Catamarca
  Chaco
  See More>>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Smarty 3.x, you can use `@iteration` property or `@index` property to count 'loop'

```
{if $ns eq 'states'}
<dt>Provincia</dt>
{foreach $r AS $k=>$v}                          
   {if $v@iteration lt 3}
    <dd>{$v}</dd>
   {else}
    <dd>Ver más<dd>
   {break}
   {/if}

{/foreach}
n = {$n}
{/if}
```

[Smarty Doc](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index)

```
<style type="text/css">
{literal}
.el-tohide {display:none;}
{/literal}
</style>

    {if $ns eq 'states'}
    <dt>Provincia</dt>
    {foreach $r AS $k=>$v}                          
        <dd class="{if $v@iteration gt 3}el-states el-tohide{/if}">{$v}</dd>
       {if $v@last && $v@iteration gt 3}
        <dd class="el-click">Ver más<dd>
       {/if}
    
    {/foreach}
    n = {$n}
   {/if}
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
$('.el-click').on('click', function (){
if ($('.el-states').hasClass('el-tohide'))
    $('.el-states').removeClass('el-tohide');
else
$('.el-states').addClass('el-tohide');
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Just AS IS not sure is functionnal but i give you the general idea. I'm supposing you're using Jquery.

Comment: Great way of simplification. But what about hiding or not showing the other elements?

Comment: @Jimena to show/hide dynamicly the others 'states' you must use a bit of JS.

Comment: @Jimena i made an update with an example of a Show/Hide solution.